# Is there a way to configure bash to always page output?

Tags: bash, shell, paging

I'd like to configure bash to page the output of all commands. Essentially, I want bash to behave as if every command I enter ended with '| less'. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$ bind '"\C-j": "|less\C-m"'
```

Or put this in your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\C-j": "|less\C-m"
```

Then when you want to do `ls -l|less` you'd type `ls -l` and press `control-J` instead of `<enter>`.

I would not recommend swapping the j and m in the bind command (or in the .inputrc file). Every time you'd press `<enter>` you'd get `|less` added which could be pretty annoying.

Comment: Potentially confusing as hell, but undeniably a neat trick.

Comment: Dennis, That rocks!
ZSH equivalent is: bindkey -s "\C-j" "|less\C-m"

Comment: @dennis-williamson, did you know how can I fix this binding, for queued commands? For example enter in bash "sleep 10", and don't wait when "sleep 10" finished, "ls" + enter, and for "ls" command "|less" will be added.

Comment: @azat: It works for me. I tried by using the `bind` command shown above (or the `.inputrc` binding), typing `sleep 10` and immediately typing `ls -l` (don't press enter) and then press Control-J (the enter is built in to the binding as `\C-m`).

Comment: @dennis-williamson, I'm probably wrong explained, I mean that if you run "sleep 5" press enter, after it, don't wait when "sleep 10" finished, "ls -l", and "less" will be added, while it shoudn't

Comment: @azat: Oh! To fix that bind the sequence to something other than Control-J and use that keystroke to add the `less` and carriage return to commands that you want. The reason for this problem is that Control-J is normally bound to `accept-line` as is Control-M (enter).

Comment: @dennis-williamson, Thanks! It works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is possible, but you can definitely make it easier on yourself by doing something like this in your .bashrc:

```
alias p='less'
```

`ll |p` then becomes a paged listing.

EDIT:  As a note though this still wont work for something that is going to STDERR.  You would need to something like:  `errorcommand 2>&1 |p`